# interchanging a partial derivative and a summation in probability

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, multivariable-calculus

Given this equation: $ \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left . \left \{ -\dfrac{1}{N}\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N \ln p(\mathbf{x}_n|\theta) \right \}\right |_{\theta_{ML}} = 0$

$\mathbf{x}_n$ is a vector of $N$ observations, $\theta$ is the parameter. $p(x|\theta)$ is the conditional probability of the observation given the parameter.

This is from the book: Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning, by Chris Bishop. He goes on to say that we can interchange the partial derivative and the summation in the following way:

$$-\displaystyle\lim_{N\to \infty}\displaystyle\frac{1}{N}\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^N \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \ln p(x_n|\theta) = E_x\left [ -\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta} \ln p(x|\theta) \right ]$$

My questions are:

1. How did the summation and the partial derivative interchange?
2. I am not sure how this transformed into an expectation.

Comment: what is $\theta_{ML}$?

Comment: Also I think the expectation occurs only upon taking the limit

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to say. $\theta_{ML}$ is the maximum likelihood estimator for the parameter $\theta$.

Comment: Also what is the issue with the interchange? It is only a finite summation, and the partial derivative is a linear operator

Comment: I am asking why it is true? Or it is supposed to be true in all cases, and just add a limiting expression? Or there are special cases when this is true?

Comment: Well there is only a potential problem if the LIMIT and the partial derivative are being interchanged. There is no problem if a finite sum is being interchanged with a partial derivative (there is a problem for an infinite sum because it is implicitly a limit). Since the interchange occurs before any limits are introduced, I don't see the potential problem.